# fs is reading the first CSV property as string. Typescript

Tags: typescript, csv, fs

I'm using fs in Typescript to read a CSV file, and it is reading fine except because I'm getting the first property as a string. For any row I'm getting this output:

```
{
  '﻿Cliente': 'text',
  nom_cli: 'text',
  sexo: '-',
  fec_nac: 'date',
  e_mail: '0',
  ind_leal: '1',
  Id_externo: '052'
}
```

and I'm using this interface to separate the fields:

```
export interface clientCSV {
    'Cliente': string;
    'nom_cli': string;
    'sexo': string;
    'fec_nac': string;
    'e_mail': string;
    'ind_leal': string;
    'Id_externo':string;
}
```

And reading the file like this:

```
fs.createReadStream(path)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row: clientCSV) => {
      console.log(row);
    })
    .on('end', async () => { ... })
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is `csv()`?

Comment: @Anatoly `const csv = require('csv-parser');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the special first character in `﻿Cliente`:

Try in browser console:

```
var a = {
  '﻿Cliente': 'text',
  nom_cli: 'text',
  sexo: '-',
  fec_nac: 'date',
  e_mail: '0',
  ind_leal: '1',
  Id_externo: '052'
}

a

Id_externo: "052"
​e_mail: "0"
​fec_nac: "date"
​ind_leal: "1"
​nom_cli: "text"
​sexo: "-"
​"\ufeffCliente": "text"
```